# Transmission distance rs485 vs ethernet

Tags: ethernet, rs485, distance, baudrate, encoding

I have a question, 
why is rs485 limited to less than 100 meters at 10mpbs ( mbaud ) 
and is 100Base-TX ethernet applicable on 100 meters with 100 mbps bitrate

i know that rs485 normally use a sort of NRZ encoding with 2 levels
and ethernet uses a MLT-3 4B5B encoding with 3 levels

but i cannot understand why the difference between distance and baudrate of
ethernet and rs485 is more than a factor 10 (ethernet has an actual baudrate of 125mbps due to 4b5b encoding)

and theoretical if 100base-tx would run at half speed would the usable distance then muliply with 2?

endgame for me would be to create an 2 wire (half-duplex) master slave (rs485-like )network with around 200 nodes , a length of 1000 meters and a speed of ~10 mbps.

or alternatively a half duplex P2P network like EtherCat but simpler like rs485 but with a usable distance of 200 meters and a speed of ~10mbps

-source of rs485 distance baudrate graph
https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/images/appnotes/3884/3884Fig06.gif

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. We don't expect every post to be perfect, but posts with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently. Remember, you can always go back at any time and edit your answer to improve it. See [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: Cost. Ethernet is more expensive (both financially and computationally than RS485). The mistake is thinking that it costs nothing to incorporate extra features into the hardware and software of a communication protocol. You would never make the same mistake with cars, right? We all COULD drive Ferraris to work, but we don't because Ferraris are expensive and we don't always need to burn rubber.

Comment: @Toor in my world, Ethernet is a consumer-grade technology and costs practically nothing, whereas RS485 endpoints typically are industrial grade technology and rather expensive.

Comment: @MarcusMüller In my world, I have to build my hardware up from almost scratch so ethernet is definitely more challenging to build and support than RS-485.

Comment: @Toor fair enough! Reading OP's question, however, I duly hope they just plug together existing network hardware.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Sitting in your ivory tower...full of ethernet switches. Let them eat ethernet.

Comment: @Toor Muhahahahaa! That isn't ivory! That is old EthernetII hubs!

Comment: @Toor to be honest, your car example kind of inspired my response: Cars use CAN where a simple RS-485 bus would do. Why? Because having a bus that does more if the endpoints have been available simply pays more than having everyone come up with a cooperation scheme for RS485. And car entertainment systems... they use gigabit ethernet.

Comment: If you have a big enough application, it pays to specialize.

Comment: i agree with @toor regarding, that ethernet is more challenging to build.
but we are only talking about layer 1 , the physical layer , why the difference is so great ,while the only difference in my viewpoint is the 3 level encoding

Comment: @Toor true! But if I was to build a network of 200 nodes spread out – I'd look for a network (not a multi-drop bus) with network segmentation, logical addressing, fault isolation. I really must say I wouldn't know how to even build a non-string 200 node RS-485 network! And I'd assume the complexity in the handling of the higher-than-physical-layer aspects would quickly "outcomplicate" the complexity of talking to an Ethernet PHY (which isn't all that complex, imho)

Comment: Yeah, each approach has different payload to overhead pay-off. RS485 has proportionally lower overhead for small payloads and number of masters, but as you scale things up that overhead scales up faster than the payload does so at some point it pays to move to something else that has a higher minimum overhead, but does not scale up as quickly.

Answer (score 2):

> but i cannot understand why the difference between distance and baudrate of ethernet and rs485 is more than a factor 10 (ethernet has an actual baudrate of 125mbps due to 4b5b encoding)

Well, Ethernet (you mention rates specific to what is called *Fast Ethernet*, by the way, not just *Ethernet*) demands better cables, and the transceivers are technically way more complex.

It's like a high-speed train goes faster than a 1960's tractor, but then again, the high-speed train is a tiny bit more complex, and needs rails.

> endgame for me would be to create an 2 wire (half-duplex) master slave (rs485-like )network with around 200 nodes , a length of 1000 meters and a speed of ~10 mbps.

Network. You say it yourself: Network. Use a networking standard that already solves all layer 2 (and above!) problems for you – RS485 really only defines how bits are exchanged between two ends of a cable. You need to come up with a working scheme to connect 200 nodes, and how to deal with collisions, and how to address nodes and …

Use ethernet. This is exactly what ethernet was built for: building medium-to-large sized networks. Switches are cheap, and reliable, and solve all problems of collisions. Ethernet offers tree-spanning, automatic discovery, switches do loop detection, support for it is available for every computer and many, many many microcontrollers…

100m work without any ado with standard Cat5 cabling (which is cheap as hell), and 1000m would be easy to build using cheap consumer switches as repeaters, or, professionally, with a media exchange to optical.

> and theoretical if 100base-tx would run at half speed would the usable distance then muliply with 2?

No. That's not how things work: The distance is limited by drive strength; while that also defines speed, there's simply no "half-speed mode" you could use.